# How to Filter a rdlc report data?

Tags: c#, winforms

In my project, I want to give a report. For that i create a report with dataset.

name, course, year, semester all the textbox datas are passing from form. (I am using parameters to passing the data). but the table datas are taken from dataset. In that dataset have all the student data. But i want display one particular student data.

For that i want to filer the data at run time in rdlc report. How can i filter the data?.

**My Form**
[image]

**Report Design**

[image]

**Mysql Table:-** In that admin_no column is there. I planed to filter the data with the help of admin_no.
[image]

Thanks in advance!.

Comment: Maybe you can pass the admin_no as a parameter into the report?

Comment: ya, i can pass,. but how to filter using that?. That is my query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter Datatable in DataSet using Select method and put returned data to another table and pass the table to the report