# How to filter data in RDLC report?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, report, rdlc

I am new to RDLC reports in Visual Studio 2010.
I am working on a Website, in this I have used report feature of VS2010. I use `ReportViewer` to show `Report1.rdlc`. It is showing it perfectly. Now my requirement is to filter data in report at runtime. I go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6314888/how-to-filter-a-rdlc-report-data) question but not able to understand it's answer.
Because `Report1.rdlc` is not available in code behind.

Now, how can I filter report's data at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

How are you getting the data from Server, etc.   Are you binding to a datatable result?  If so, you can just have your query apply the filter when extracting data to begin with so you don't have to do anything special in the actual report.

Per your feedback, if you are getting a DataTable, then applying a filter should be easy like

```
DataTable oDT = YourSQLCommandToGetData();
oDT.DefaultView.RowFilter = "SomeColumn = x and OtherColumn = y";
```

And then run your report.  If you want to take it to another level and ENSURE you don't have any unwanted records, you could even do something like

```
DataTable oNewFilteredResult = oDT.DefaultView.ToTable();
```

Then, you can assign the NEW table to call the RDLC.

Comment: Yes I am binding to a datatable, but wizard not giving any query option. It is only asking table name. I am using SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Surely you assign the dataset to the rdlc report, and in the page of your reportviewer, you would be using an object datasource (and therefor an XSD dataset with datatables), which encapsulates the query.

The query naturally has a **where** clause, in which you insert your parameters to filter the data by, like:

```
WHERE (Table.Field = @Param OR @Param = A_Default_Value)
```

Now add the controls you like to the page before calling the report (drop-down lists, textboxes, etc..), those controls filter the Object datasource, which is mapped to a dataset in the rdlc report, and thus, the report would be filterd upon clicking on a certain button, e.g. **Show Report**, to refresh the object datasources (databinding them) and re-showing the report in the reportviewer.

You may consider assiging the values of the filtering controls to parameters in the rdlc, so that you may show the parameters of the report in its header upon generating it:

```
Parameters!ParameterName.Value
```

Hope that helps you.